# Find the area of an isosceles trapezoid $ABCD$ $(AB\parallel CD)$ with height $m$ and perpendicular diagonals $(AC\perp BD)$

Tags: geometry

Find the area of an isosceles trapezoid $ABCD$ $(AB\parallel CD)$ with height $m$ and perpendicular diagonals $(AC\perp BD)$.

The area of $ABCD$ is given by $$S_{ABCD}=\dfrac{a+b}{2}.h=\dfrac{a+b}{2}.m$$
where $a$ and $b$ are the two bases $(a>b)$. So we have to find $a+b$ in terms of $m$ or maybe even $\dfrac{a+b}{2}$. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Draw a diagram. Diagonals will make $45^0$ angle with parallel sides. $a+b = 2m$

Comment: @MathLover, I do have a diagram. Why $a+b=2m$?  Thank you!

Comment: Say diagonals meet at $O$ and one of the bases is $AB$. What are the angles where diagonals meet? All of them are $90^0$. As it is isosceles trapezoid, $OA = OB$ and $\angle AOB = 90^0$.

Comment: same is true for $\triangle OCD$. Now say perp from $O$ to $AB$ is $x$ then $O$ to $CD$ is $(m-x)$. See if you can work this out from here.

Comment: @MathLover, I really can't work it from here. I tried to use $\dfrac{x}{m-x}=\dfrac{a}{b}$ but it didn't work. Thank you!

Comment: Drop a perp from $O$ to $AB$. Say it meets at $H$. Then $\triangle OHB$ is a right angled triangle with one of the angles being $45^0$ so the other is $45^0$ too. $OH = HB = AB/2$ and $OH = x$ So $AB = 2x$. Similarly $CD = 2(m-x)$. Add them to get $2m$.

Comment: @MathLover, thank you, I got it.

Comment: Can't resist alternative approach: Assume long base is $\overline{AD}$ of length $(2x + b)$, short base is $\overline{BC}$ of length $(b)$.  Then $(a+b) = (2x + 2b)$.  Further, the two diagonals have slopes $\frac{m}{x+b}$ and $\frac{-m}{x+b}$.  Since these two diagonals are given to be perpendicular, this implies that $\frac{m}{x+b} = \frac{x+b}{m} \implies m = (x+b).$

Comment: Just to add a geometric viewpoint to the problem: Let AB be the short side and drop two perpendiculars to the "bottom" CD.  Now you have a rectangle and two identical right triangles which you can join to form one rectangle at height m.  Use any other known, i.e. diagonal or side, to calculate the area.

Answer (score 1):

The trapezoid is *isoceles*, hence $\,\overline{AC} = \overline{BD}\,$ in:

[image]

Given the above coordinate system, we have for the diagonals, with a bit of analytic geometry:
$$
\overline{AD} \; : \; \begin{cases} x = -a/2 + (b/2+a/2)t \\ y = mt \quad ; \quad 0 \le t \le 1 \end{cases}
\quad \Longrightarrow \quad x-(a/2+b/2)y/m=-a/2 \\
\overline{BC} \; : \; \begin{cases} x = +a/2 - (b/2+a/2)t \\ y = mt \quad ; \quad 0 \le t \le 1 \end{cases}
\quad \Longrightarrow \quad x+(a/2+b/2)y/m=+a/2
$$
The diagonals are perpendicular to each other if the
[dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition)
of the normals of the line segments $\overline{AD}$ and $\overline{BC}$ is zero:
$$
\left(1,-\frac{a/2+b/2}{m}\right)\cdot\left(1,+\frac{a/2+b/2}{m}\right) = 1-\frac{(a/2+b/2)^2}{m^2} = 0
\\ \Longrightarrow \quad m = \frac{a+b}{2}
$$
$$
\mbox{Area} = m^2 = \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2
$$

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.-The problem seems indeterminate because in the area between two parallels whose distance is equal to $m$, if only the fact that they are perpendicular diagonals is given as additional data and the problem were determined then the answer would be equal to $m^2$ because a square side $m$ satisfies the conditions of the problem. But it does not appear to be the case for any other trapezoid as shown in the accompanying figure.

[image]